# Authenticating a login page without procedures in SQLite3

Tags: java, jquery, sqlite, authentication, jdbc

I am trying to make a basic login page(not specifically for a website), and I am using SQLite3 for storing the usernames and passwords. Signing Up(registering) a new username is simple as I just need to enter insert the values into the database through SQLite3's java connector. However, Signing In requires me to compare the entered username and password with its corresponding values in the database. Is there any way to do this comparison without creating procedures/functions as SQLite does not support them?

If there is another way of doing this through java, please show me what the code should be like.

Comment: Why would you need a stored procedure? You can query for the user data, can't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ResultSet object can be used to store the result set that is obtained from the select query. The database password can be stored into a variable by calling the getString function of the result set object by passing the attribute name, say userPassword. Then compare this value with the entered password for authenticating. Here is a demo of just the signIn method:

```
private boolean authenticate() {
    if (usernameField.getText().length() == 0
            || passwordField.getPassword().length == 0) {
        errorLabel.setText("Error! Please fill in the required fields.");
        errorLabel.setVisible(true);
    } else {          
        Connection connection = null;    // for establishing a connection to the database
        Statement statement = null;     // for querying the database
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Login.db");
            //Established Connection
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            // query to be executed
            String sqlQuery = "select * from login where username = '"
                    + usernameField.getText() + "'";
            // result of the executed query
            ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            String databasePassword = null;       
            // Storing the password from the database
            if (queryResult.next()) {
                databasePassword = queryResult.getString("userpass");
            }
            String enteredPassword = new String(passwordField.getPassword()); 
            // Storing the entered password from the form
            if (enteredPassword.equals(databasePassword)) {
                return true;
                // User is now authenticated and you may enter your redirecting page code here
            } else {
                errorLabel.setText("Invalid username or password. Try again.");
                errorLabel.setVisible(true);
            }
            statement.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " : " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When the method returns true, you can redirect the flow to another method which will log the user into the portal.

Answer (score 0):

For both:  JEE application and eventual not-JEE solution you need to query your database with something like:

```
select password from users where user = :user
```

For JEE it would be done by JEE container but should be configured anyway.

After that you need to compare with password given by the user.

For security reason it is recommended to store properly hashed passwords in database to avoid dictionary attacks. In hashing scenario before storing and before comparing you need to process the given password with the same algorithm.